# How to determine if a so file has been loaded or not?

Tags: c, linux, windows, dll, shared-libraries

I have two shared libraries: a.so and b.so.

a.so must have be loaded before b.so is loaded. And, a.so might be loaded by other modules, not by me.

So, I want to determine if a.so has been loaded before I call `dlopen("b.so", ...)`.

Under Windows, I can use `GetModuleHandle("a.dll")` to determine that by examining the return value. That is, a.dll has been loaded if the return value is not null; otherwise it is not loaded yet.

Is there a GetModuleHandle-like function under Linux?

Comment: Why not a boolean variable that you yourself set when you load `a.so`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, a.so may be loaded by other modules, not by me.

Comment: Then why not simply make `b.so` depend on `a.so`, so the system will load `a.so` automatically when `b.so` is loaded?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's indeed a solution. But I still want to know a so's loading state at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) to check this, with the `RTLD_NOLOAD` flag:

> Don't load the library.  This can be used to test if the library is already resident (`dlopen()` returns `NULL` if it is not, or the library's handle if it is resident).

Comment: Thank you very much, Joachim. That's just what I'm looking for.

Comment: @xmllmx While this correctly answer original question, the question itself shows that you are likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> determine if a.so has been loaded before I call dlopen

That is almost certainly the wrong thing to do (i.e. you are asking the wrong question).

Consider a multithreaded program, where you ask above question (and receive positive answer) in thread 1, just as thread 2 calls `dlclose(a_so_handle)`s and unloads `a.so`.

Conversely, you may get a negative answer in thread 1, just as thread 2 *finishes* `dlopen("a.so", ...)`, and loads it.

The right thing to do is simply do `dlopen("a.so", ...); dlopen("b.so", ...);`.

If a.so has already been loaded, the first `dlopen` will simply increment its reference count. If it has not yet been loaded, it will be.

> But I still want to know a so's loading state at runtime.

You can't know that state *reliably*. The answer you are getting is: `a.so` may or may not be currently loaded.

Comment: This is also true on Windows, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dl_iterate_phdr**.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <link.h>

    int dl_iterate_phdr(
             int (*callback) (struct dl_phdr_info *info,
                              size_t size, void *data),
             void *data);
```

Callback takes struct dl_phdr_info which has dlpi_name member. There is a simple example in **dl_iterate_phdr(3)**.